# If elements not of order 2 form a subgroup of index $2$, then it is abelian.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group.
Let
$$
H=\{ x\in G\mid x^2\ne e\}\cup\{e\}.
$$
Assume that $H$ is a subgroup and $2\lvert H\rvert=\lvert G\rvert$.
Then $H$ is an abelian group of odd order.

I want to prove the above claim.
It was easy for me that $H$ has odd order.
In fact, if $x\in H$ has order $2n$, then $x^n\in H$ has order $2$, a contradiction.

However, I do not know how to show that $H$ is abelian.
Let $x,y\in H$.
Then I could show that $xy$, $x^{-1}y^{-1}$ are commutative, but I cannot go further.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $x \notin H$ and $h \in H$, then $xh$ has order $2$. This gives $xhx=h^{-1}$, in other words the inner automorphism $\varphi_x: G \to G$ (recall that $x=x^{-1}$) restricts to an automorphism of $H$ given $h \mapsto h^{-1}$. Now, it is well-known that the "inverse map" $u \mapsto u^{-1}$ on a group $U$ is an automorphism if and only if the group is abelian.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood.